# Inserting data from JS script into mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have created a script to count down whatever value I submit into a form and then output "the submitted value + the date of the moment I clicked on the submit button" as a result.

But now I want to store the result into my database every time I use the form by using SQL query and then echo all of these results in another page named "log.php" using SELECT SQL query.

```
var timelog = [];

function myF() {
    countdown(s);
    log = document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = s + 'at ' + new Date();
    timelog.push(log);
}

function logged() {
    document.getElementById("timeloggg").innerHTML = timelog;
}
```

I have tried to assign the result to a variable, but obviously, I cant use this variable outside of the script.

With some googling, I was told to use Ajax, but sadly I couldn't figure out how to insert the data using ajax, because all of the code examples out there are only about calling data from the database.

So any advice on how to insert the result into my database? I'm still a beginner so please explain in detail if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, of course, to insert data into your database from client side js, BUT DONT!  I can't think of a way to do it that would not expose your database credentials, leaving you open to malicious actors.

What you need to do is set up a php script on your server, then send the data (either by POST or GET) you want inserted to that with an xhr request, and let that php script do the insert.  HOWEVER, there is quite a bit to securing even that.  Google "how to sanitize mysql inputs in php" and read several articles on it.

Depending on what you need to do, you can sanitize the inputs yourself, but the recommended way to do it is with prepared statements, which you will need to read the documentation for your specific implementation, whether it's mysqli or pdo in mySQL or some other library (say if you're using SQL, postGRE, Oracle, etc).

HTH

=================================================

Here is how to do it in js, BUT DONT DO THIS, unless you are never going to expose this code outside of your local computer.

```
var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
var connectionstring = "Provider=host;Data Source=table;User Id=user;Password=pass;";
connection.Open(connectionstring);

var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
var sql = {{your sql statement}};
rs.Open(sql, connection);

connection.close;
```

==============================================

For php, do something like this, replacing host, user, pass, db with your actual credentials and hostname and database:

```
$db = new mysqli({host}, {user}, {pass}, {database});
if($db->connect_errno > 0){ die ("Unable to connect to database [{$db->connect_error}]"); }
```

to set the connection.  If this is a publicly accessible php server, then there are rules about how to set up the connection so that you don't accidentally expose your credentials, but I'm going to skip that for now.  You would basically save this into a file that's not accessible from the outside (above the document root, for instance) and then include it, but database security is a complex topic.

To get the values you passed in the query string of your ajax call:

```
$val1 = $_GET['val1'];
$val2 = $_GET['val2'];
```

Then to do the insert with a parameterized query:

```
$query = $db->prepare("
    INSERT INTO your_table (field1, field2)
    VALUES (?, ?)
");
$query->bind_param('ss', $val1, $val2);
$query->execute();
```

Now, here you're going to have to look at the documentation.  'ss' means that it's going to treat both of those values you're inserting as strings.  I don't know the table set up, so you'll have to look up the right code for whatever you are actually inserting, like if they were integers, then 'ii', or 'si' would mean the first value was a string and the second one was an int.

Here are the allowed values:

i - integer
d - double
s - string
b - BLOB

but look at the documentation for prepared statements anyway.  I used msqli in this example.

Comment: Well, this will mostly be a local project, im not planning on releasing it to the public, just a tool to help my personal work. Ye maybe in the future i will have to release it, but atm im not. So im just looking for a solution regardless of sanitizing the inputs.
Also, can you explain a lil bit more how to send the data that i want to insert with an xhr request? thanks

Comment: Sure, no problem.  You still want to set up a php script on your server, though.  That will likely be easier than doing the insert in js.  Set up a php script, say insert.php.  Then call that from ajax using a query string, like: insert.php?val=test.  Then in your insert.php, add this line: echo "<pre>"; print_r($_GET); echo "</pre>"; exit; and you'll see how the query string variables are stored, in this case it would be $_GET['val'].  Then write your mysql statement using that value.  You will still need to secure the inputs if your php script can be accessed from the internet.

Comment: This is probably a little bit too complex to do in comments.  Tell me what database you are using, and I'll edit the original answer.

Comment: im using Mysql database

Comment: sorry for the late answer, yes i have

Comment: I edited the answer to give some basic instruction on how to do it both from js and from php.

Comment: i have tried the JS way, changing the db connection data with my host name, host username, etc + added my sql statement inside the {{}} and it caused the whole functions to stop working, so i removed the {{}} and used "the sql query here" instead and the functions were working again, but the whole script of inserting data into my db didnt work.. no data has been inserted into my table.

Comment: even the PHP way doesnt insert the data, only the id and thats it. i have used $time = $_GET['data']; in my php file. while using var params = 'data=' + log; and http.send(params); in the ajax call, so i dunno what is wrong here.. even if i pass any other string like 'fname=whatever' it wont work.

Comment: if you'll give me the db structure and the js and php code you tried, I'll set up an identical table on my mySQL db and troubleshoot the code.  Strip out your credentials, I won't need them and you shouldn't share them.

Comment: Well, the PHP way + AJAX actually worked for me, i was using $_GET instead of $_POST. But the JS way still doesnt work anyways..

my db structure is very simple, just one table with 2 columns (id and date) thats it.
the JS code i tried is :
```
var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
var connectionstring = // my host details + db name or table name
connection.Open(connectionstring);

var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
var sql = "INSERT INTO testing (id, logged) VALUES (NULL, 'log')"; // log is variable
rs.Open(sql, connection);

connection.close;
```

Comment: sorry, I think that JS way may only work for IE.  I didn't really think about it.  But if you have a php script at least partially set up, and you are successfully sending the data there with ajax, do that instead.  It is the preferred way.   Can I see your php code?  Again, remove your credentials.

Comment: ye sure why not, here it is:

include "db_connect.php";

$dateandtime = $_POST['dateandtime'];

// to be able to use ' and things like that in the entry
$loggedtime = addslashes($dateandtime);

$query = $mysqli->prepare("
    INSERT INTO log (time)
    VALUES (?)
");
$query->bind_param('s', $dateandtime);
$query->execute();
$mysqli->close();

and thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225077/discussion-between-chris-strickland-and-mido-h).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check Ajax requests.

I would suggest to [start here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp).

What you will do is basically create asynchronous requests from javascript to a php file on your server.

> Ajax allows web pages to be updated asynchronously by exchanging small
> amounts of data with the server behind the scenes. This means that it
> is possible to update parts of a web page, without reloading the whole
> page.